# Calculate difference between 24 bit colors without splitting into seperate RGB bytes?

Tags: algorithm, math, colors

Normal approach to calculate distance between colors is probably this:

```
//             R G B
var color1 = 0xFF0000;
var color2 = 0x00FF00;
// Calculate points      R                    G                  B
var color1_p = [(color1&0xFF0000)>>16, (color1&0xFF00)>>8, color1&0xFF];
var color2_p = [(color2&0xFF0000)>>16, (color2&0xFF00)>>8, color2&0xFF];

var distance = Math.sqrt((color1_p[0]-color2_p[0])*(color1_p[0]-color2_p[0]) + 
                         (color1_p[1]-color2_p[1])*(color1_p[1]-color2_p[1]) +
                         (color1_p[2]-color2_p[2])*(color1_p[2]-color2_p[2]))
```

This is just normal Pythagorean distance. But I have to create an array or otherwise save the RGB values. I could workaround this in C++ I guess:

```
uint32_t color = 0xFF0000;
uint8_t* color_p = (uint8_t*)&color; // [G, B, R, alpha, segmentation fault ...]
```

[You can try it here.](http://ideone.com/L8hJqs) Never do this with `int`, it can range from 16 to 64 bits on some weird platforms.

Now my question is, if there's some smart math that can be done directly on the numbers like `0xFF0000` (red, `16711680` dec) and `0xFFCC00` (orange, `16763904` dec) to calculate distance or other kind of difference. I'm looking for linear difference. By linear difference I mean that if **distance** between A and B is the same, the difference must also be the same, but I don't care what number exactly it is.

Comment: There are other distance metrics, but what exactly are you trying to avoid here? Creating an array is trivial to avoid here and I'm not sure what "saving" implies in "save the RGB values" (you certainly don't have to keep them around for any length of time).

Comment: @harold I'm trying to avoid temporary variables at all.

Comment: @harold Integer (call it `diff`) ranging from `0` to `N` such as for every number `dist` representing distance between points representing colour's RGB, there's one `diff`. That means `diff` is some linear space that is produced by multiplying `dist` space by number greater or equal to one.

Comment: That sqrt is an expensive operation.  If you don't care about the actual values but only the ranking you can omit it.

Comment: If you could actually compute such a measure, you could trivially calculate the actual distance from it. So you probably can't do it with a shortcut.

Comment: I see some confusion in the comments about what exactly you're asking. May I suggest the title "Calculate difference between 24 bit colors without splitting into seperate RGB bytes?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no avoiding the 3-dimensional nature of the calculation. A calculation using the 3-byte integer value would not respect the independence of the dimensions. The only thing you can safely do with the integer values is check for equality, which would indeed be more efficient than comparing the 3 bytes seperately (if you have a lot of identical RGB values).
You can optimize the calculation in a number of ways, but splitting the colours into seperate R, G and B values will always be part of it. Something like this will be the most efficient you can make this:

```js
function rgbDistanceSquared(x, y) {
    if (x == y) return 0;    // if you expect a lot of identical RGB values
    var r = ((x & 0xFF0000) - (y & 0xFF0000)) >> 16;
    var g = ((x & 0x00FF00) - (y & 0x00FF00)) >> 8;
    var b =  (x & 0x0000FF) - (y & 0x0000FF);
    return r * r + g * g + b * b;
}

document.write(rgbDistanceSquared(0xFF0000, 0xFFCC00) + "<BR>");
document.write(rgbDistanceSquared(0x00CCFF, 0x0000FF) + "<BR>");
document.write(rgbDistanceSquared(0x00CCFF, 0xFFCC00) + "<BR>");
```

The above code returns the distance squared, to avoid having to calculate the square root. 
When checking equality or comparing distances this makes no difference, because:
A < B → A<sup>2</sup> < B<sup>2</sup>
A = B → A<sup>2</sup> = B<sup>2</sup>
A > B → A<sup>2</sup> > B<sup>2</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As @harold mentioned there are other distance metrics. The simplest being the [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) or taxicab metric. This basically calculates the sum of the absolute values. If you points were (r1,g1,b1) and (r2,g2,b2) find |r1-r2| + |g1-g2| + |b1-b2|. Its called the Manhattan distance as it measures the distance you would travel between two points if you can only move along the edges of a rectangular grid, like the road pattern in Manhattan.

Let c1=0xrrggbb be single byte representation of (r1,g1,b1) and similar for c2.
If we knew r2>=r1, g2>=g1, b2>=b1 we could just find `x=c2-c1`, `y=((x & 0xFF0000)>>16)+((x & 0x00FF00)>>8)+(x & 0x0000FF)`. If the points can be in any order then we have to worry about each byte overflowing.

Hackers delight has a nice way of finding the absolute value. If have a signed 32 bit integer `x` then we can calculate `y = x >> 32; z=(x+y)^x`. Gives the absolute value. We could do something like

```
int32_t r = ((c1 & 0xFF0000) - (c2 & 0xFF0000)) >> 16;
int32_t rsign = r >> 32; // fill with sign bit
int32_t result = (r+rsign)^r;
int32_t g = ((c1 & 0x00FF00) - (c2 & 0x00FF00)) >> 8;
int32_t gsign = g >> 32; // fill with sign bit
result += (g+gsign)^g;
int32_t b = ((c1 & 0x0000FF) - (c2 & 0x0000FF));
int32_t bsign = b >> 32; // fill with sign bit
result += (b+bsign)^b;
```

I think this takes 23 operations. It does not really offer an advantage over @m69's answer and integer multiplication is fast on modern hardware.